# How to fix this problem with Camera Permission on iPad on iOS 12.3.1?

Tags: ios, arkit

I've just had an arkit app rejected after review by Apple. Specifically, a bug with iPad usage running iOS 12.3.1

Here is the feedback I received.

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running 12.3.1 on Wi-Fi.

Specifically, after starting the game, app did not request access to camera and no further action took place.

The info.plist privacy key (Privacy - Camera Usage Description) is set with an explanation that the app needs access to the camera for an augmented reality experience.

But according to the tester my augmented reality app did not ask for permission to use the camera on the iPad. The app does ask for permission on my iPhone running 12.3.1 so I am curious why the iPad version does not do this? I can't verify the issue as I don't own an iPad with an A9 Chip or better.

What code should I be using to test if the camera permission is given or not and handling that response accordingly?

I'd like to ensure my camera permissions is being handled properly to resolve this issue and before the scene is allowed to start. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You should edit your question to show the code where you request camera access and what your app does if it is unknown or denied. It sounds like you have a race condition of some sort.  Permission is granted asynchronously

Comment: I understand. But iOS should ask for permission to use the camera automatically without any code and in this case it did on the iPhone but not on the testers iPad and so my app was rejected. Unless, I am missing something.

Comment: I am having the same problem! How did you solve it?